# Jquery Working with a DropDown List

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I know this has been asked before, but this is a slight variation.
I know how to change the selected value of a dropdown using with the selectedIndex or the option value..

```
  $("#colA"+id).prop("selectedIndex", 0);
  $("#colA"+id).val("1");
```

But can it be done for the option TEXT. eg:

```
<option value='1234'>**Entry 1**</option>
```

Can we change based on **Entry 1** ? The value is dynamic, the text is static.
I can't find anyway to do this especially as I'm using `$("#colA"+id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using :

```
 var defaultVal = "Event 1";
  $("#ColA"+id).each(function () {
    $('option', this).each(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).text().toLowerCase()) == $.trim(defaultVal.toLowerCase())) {
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        };
      });
    });
```